# Were the priests that served in the unsanctioned Temple in the northern kingdom Levites?

Tags: levites-leviyim

I wouldn't think that the Levites would agree to serve in an unsanctioned Temple, often making offerings to Ba'al.

Comment: See Judges 17:7-13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verse ([Kings 1:12:31](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.12.31?ven=The_Metsudah_Tanach_series,_Lakewood,_N.J&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)) is clear that Jeroboam appointed new priests, not from the tribe of Levi:

> And he made the house of altars, and he appointed as priests some of the people, who were not of the sons [tribe] of Leivi.